# Varnish+Nginx+Magento cannot serve same page multiple times, resp 502

Tags: php, magento, caching, nginx

I have been on the administrative side of a small Magento 2 developers team. They have been setting all their Magento 1 installations behind nginx and php-fpm7.1

I got huge troubles debugging Varnish since it requires a great understanding of header fields and Varnish states.

So they decided to start doing demos with Magento 2 but we noticed that the performance compared to Magento 1 (same stack) is terrible. Nginx could serve 3k requests per second with Magento 1.9.2 and there is a decline to 50 requests per second. Of course Magento 2.2.1 full page cache is not working so they asked of me to setup Varnish, as recommended.

**EDIT** :

It was about checkout and admin panel only. I was wrong. The problem is not actually only on these places. The problem is everywhere and shows up for almost a second after a succesful request is made. If I load the landing page 5 times in a row only the 1st time will get a 200 and the rest a 502. Also found out that varnishstat gets reset every time i get the 502 error, so i am adding varnishadm panic.show

**EDIT 2** :

<del>Problem is not on one request per second. Problem is serving the same Page in one second that leads to this. I can't measure the exact timeframe but it sure happens only when same page is requested in a small timeframe. 
Problem still exists on admin panels manual jobs(cache flush, re index etc.).</del>

Problem seems to happen after a page gets cached once and requested back again.After visiting a page and requesting it back even after some seconds (not 1 that I thought, removed previous edit).

**Varnishadm panic log shown below** (running out of chars)

[varnishadm panic log](https://pastebin.com/GRYqR2e0)

**The Setup**:

- Nginx serves at ports 80/443 and passes all traffic to Varnish at port 6081(def port).
- Varnish works with Magento generated VCL and if needed redirects to Backend at 8080.

**The problem:**
*See the edit above.*

<del>Typical backend jobs, like cache flush, and www.mymagento.com/Checkout/ lead to 502.
Whenever i try to add something to a cart, and go to checkout i get a 502.
Whenever  flush the cache or re-index data i get a 502.</del>

**What does nginx report on the time of event?**

```
2017/12/14 16:16:08 [error] 17110#17110: *236271 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 91.140.10.184, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6081/", host: "dom.com"
2017/12/14 16:16:08 [info] 17110#17110: *236323 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9007", host: "dom.com"
2017/12/14 16:16:08 [error] 17110#17110: *236271 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.140.10.184, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6081/", host: "dom.com"
2017/12/14 16:16:09 [error] 17110#17110: *236271 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 91.140.10.184, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6081/", host: "dom.com"
2017/12/14 16:16:09 [info] 17110#17110: *236332 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9007", host: "dom.com"
2017/12/14 16:16:09 [error] 17110#17110: *236271 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.140.10.184, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6081/", host: "dom.com"
2017/12/14 16:16:09 [error] 17110#17110: *236271 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 91.140.10.184, server: dom.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6081/", host: "dom.com"
```

**Varnish log**

```
*   << BeReq    >> 294951
-   Begin          bereq 294950 pass
-   Timestamp      Start: 1513009334.530160 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /checkout/
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
-   BereqHeader    Host: www.mymagento.com
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: www.mymagento.com
-   BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: 37.6.210.242
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    Content-Length: 0
-   BereqHeader    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0
-   BereqHeader    accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
-   BereqHeader    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.5
-   BereqHeader    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   BereqHeader    referer: https://www.mymagento.com/catalog/product/view/id/3350/s/1510911799-kalson-elafaki-mayro/category/41/
-   BereqHeader    upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    cookie: _ga=GA1.2.2063407653.1510934108; __zlcmid=jpgwnJ1tBFQDKV; intercom-session-xmx5ec9n=dWh5bmg4Y29Sb2FZUW9ybEN6YzJSVGpycE1CZkQvK0hhZnFJYmhNOTJmems0d3p3NkgvSWNORmVVcFRneTVFMy0tOG5JTXJ3aHFYRFlnaTUvbmM4Z1BQZz09--5a2e1ecdcaf4577b3b82a02ad1271c00b50931b1
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 37.6.210.242, 127.0.0.1
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 294951
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Backend        14 default default(127.0.0.1,,8080)
-   Timestamp      Bereq: 1513009334.530267 0.000107 0.000107
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1513009334.720461 0.190301 0.190194
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   200
-   BerespReason   OK
-   BerespHeader   Server: nginx
-   BerespHeader   Date: Mon, 11 Dec 2017 16:22:14 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   BerespHeader   Connection: close
-   BerespHeader   Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   BerespHeader   X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: form_key=HitLxJK4OFvkFpFq; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-2017 17:22:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mage2secure.magedeploy.com
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: form_key=HitLxJK4OFvkFpFq; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-2017 17:22:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mage2secure.magedeploy.com
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=suasda12321sgrb840ebodav186; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-2017 17:22:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=www.mymagento.com; secure; HttpOnly
-   BerespHeader   Set-Cookie: X-Magento-Vary=7f0ec19209469e9c448407b53fa5e756e55a0200; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
-   BerespHeader   Pragma: no-cache
-   BerespHeader   Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
-   BerespHeader   Expires: Sun, 11 Dec 2016 16:22:14 GMT
-   BerespHeader   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   BerespHeader   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   BerespHeader   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   TTL            RFC 0 -1 -1 1513009335 1513009335 1513009334 1481473334 0
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_RESPONSE
-   TTL            VCL -1 259200 0 1513009335
-   TTL            VCL 120 259200 0 1513009335
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   BerespHeader   Content-Encoding: gzip
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   ObjProtocol    HTTP/1.1
-   ObjStatus      200
-   ObjReason      OK
-   ObjHeader      Server: nginx
-   ObjHeader      Date: Mon, 11 Dec 2017 16:22:14 GMT
-   ObjHeader      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
-   ObjHeader      Vary: Accept-Encoding
-   ObjHeader      X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.26
-   ObjHeader      Set-Cookie: form_key=HitLxJK4OFvkFpFq; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-2017 17:22:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mage2secure.magedeploy.com
-   ObjHeader      Set-Cookie: form_key=HitLxJK4OFvkFpFq; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-2017 17:22:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mage2secure.magedeploy.com
-   ObjHeader      Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=su53asdad223sgrb83dav186; expires=Mon, 11-Dec-2017 17:22:14 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=mage2secure.magedeploy.com; secure; HttpOnly
-   ObjHeader      Set-Cookie: X-Magento-Vary=7f0ec19209469e9c448407b53fa5e756e55a0200; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
-   ObjHeader      Pragma: no-cache
-   ObjHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
-   ObjHeader      Expires: Sun, 11 Dec 2016 16:22:14 GMT
-   ObjHeader      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
-   ObjHeader      X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
-   ObjHeader      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
-   ObjHeader      Content-Encoding: gzip
-   Fetch_Body     4 eof -
-   VSL            flush
-   End            synth
```

**Varnish VCL**

```
vcl 4.0; import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 4.0 For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto:
# https'
backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 900s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}
acl purge {
    "localhost";
}
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header has been added to the response in
        # your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's
        # deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }

        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }
    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          #was pi pe
          return (pass);
    }
    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }
    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }
    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";
    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");
    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);
    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unkown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }
    # Remove Google gclid parameters to minimize the cache objects
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+$",""); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"\?gclid=[^&]+&","?"); # strips when QS = "?gclid=AAA&foo=bar"
    set req.url = regsuball(req.url,"&gclid=[^&]+",""); # strips when QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA" or QS = "?foo=bar&gclid=AAA&bar=baz"
    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
#        return (hash);
        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and
        #uncommenting next 3 lines
        unset req.http.Https;
        unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        unset req.http.Cookie;
    }
    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }
    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }
    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
    if (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)iPhone") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)iPod") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)BlackBerry") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)Palm") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)Googlebot\-Mobile") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)Windows Mobile") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)Android") {
        hash_data("8");
    } elsif (req.http.user-agent ~ "(?i)Opera") {
        hash_data("8");
    }
}
sub vcl_backend_response {
    set beresp.grace = 3d;
    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }
    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }
    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }
    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }
   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
        beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
        (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control && beresp.http.Vary == "*")) {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }
    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}
sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (fetch);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

**Nginx Site Config**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.mymagento.com;
        location /.well-known/ {
                default_type "text/plain";
                try_files $uri =404;
        }
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        server_name www.mymagento.com;

        listen 443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/magento/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/magento/privkey.pem;

#       port_in_redirect off;

        include https_basic.conf;

        keepalive_timeout 0s;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#        proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }
}


server {
        server_name www.mymagento.com;
        listen 8080;

        root /home/magento/public_html/pub/;

        set $HTTPS_FORWARD on;

        index index.php;
        charset UTF-8;
        error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
        expires off;

        # PHP entry point for setup application
        location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
        root    /home/kirakalo/public_html/;
        location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        #       if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9007;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

                fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
#               access_log /var/log/nginx/phpfpmonly-access.log;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
        }

        # PHP entry point for update application
        location ~* ^/update($|/) {
                root /home/kirakalo/public_html/;

            location ~ ^/update/index.php {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9007;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;

                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        #       fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
#               access_log /var/log/nginx/phpfpmonly-access.log;
            }

        # Deny everything but index.php
        location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location /pub/ {
                location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*.xml) {
                        deny all;
                }
                alias /home/kirakalo/public_html/pub/;
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

                location ~ ^/pub/static/version {
                        rewrite ^/pub/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /pub/static/$2 last;
                }

        }


        location /static/ {
        # Uncomment the following line in production mode
#       expires max;

        # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
        location ~ ^/static/version {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
        }

        location ~* .(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires +1y;

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
                }
        }
        location ~* .(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
                add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires    off;

                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
                }
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$1 last;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }


        location /media/ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* .(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
#        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* .(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}


location ~ (health_check|op1337|index|get|static|report|404|503).php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9007;   
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $HTTPS_FORWARD;

#    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
#    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/phpfpmonly-access.log;
}

location ~* (.php$|.htaccess$|.git) {
    deny all;
}

}
```

Where is the problem hiding ?Is this bad config or maybe related to the teams code? I am completely new to Varnish and trying to figure this out has become a complete headache.

Edit: Noticed that when I log in as a user to the page the cart is filled even if I login/logout. Note that There is a page that you get to see your cart items. This pages response seems to be "Your cart is empty" even if there is a box on the top that shows items-to-buy and quantities/price.

[cart problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmSDZ.png)

**Note** :
This problem only exists after varnish came in the picture. As I said already server could handle only up to ~100 requests per second with Magento 2 which is an actually terrible number.

Comment: (Aside: the multiple edits of this question made it rather hard to read, which I have tried to fix up a bit, as far as I understood it. Old material turned into quotes that were not actually quotes, and stuff became crossed out, which will be rather confusing for new readers. It's worth noting that, unlike other sites on the web, **future readers is who we write for here**. Thus, questions are best written either by (1) merging in edits seamlessly where possible, or (2) using chronological edits addenda that do not disturb the original question).

Comment: Thanks for pointing these problems.
Will do my best to keep it as clean as possible in future posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up reaching the #varnish channel on IRC and asking for help. So [Guillaume Quintard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6649816/guillaume-quintard) pointed out the error.

If we inspect the `panic.show` log on line 8 of pastebin we can see the overflow keyword.

```
ws = 0x7f285f09f0e0 { OVERFLOW
```

The rest of the message refers to the backend's response. So in the end what it means is the headers of the backend's reply were bigger than varnish could handle.

**Solution :**
Increase the parameter workspace_backend. He suggested I double it up.

By running **varnishadm param.show** you can trace the value assigned and try to double it up. I went from 64k to 128k.

To assign the new value add to your varnish.params file, on the DAEMON OPTS context the parameter and value like :

```
-p workspace_backend=n
```

where n->bytes.

Kudos to you dear Guillaume and varnish-software team for the assistance.